# How to check if an Asset field is empty within a Matrix row

Tags: matrix, assets

How can you check if there is an image within an Asset field within a Matrix field.

I have tried

```
{matrixField search:asset="not IS_EMPTY"}
```

and

```
{matrixField} 
{if asset != ''}
```

But it still does it anyway. I have updated to the latest Matrix but still have issues.

Answer (score 1):

Would not the simple method work ?:

```
{matrixfield}
    {if assetfield}
        {assetfield}
    {/if}
    {anothermatrixcolumn}
    {/anothermatrixcolumn}
{/matrixfield}
```